# PHP - replace values in sub array

Tags: php, replace, arrays

I have two arrays $pq and $rs. please see them below:

```
$pq = array ('page-0'=>array ('line-0'=>array('item-0'=>array('name'=>"item-00",'value'=>"123"),
                                           'item-1'=>array('name'=>"item-01",'value'=>"456")
                                            ),
                            'line-1'=>array('item-0'=>array('name'=>"item-10",'value'=>"789"),
                                           'item-1'=>array('name'=>"item-11",'value'=>"012")
                                            )),

'page-1'=>array ('line-0'=>array('item-0'=>array('name'=>"item-100",'value'=>"345"),
                                           'item-1'=>array('name'=>"item-101",'value'=>"678")
                                            ),
                            'line-1'=>array('item-0'=>array('name'=>"item-110",'value'=>"901"),
                                           'item-1'=>array('name'=>"item-111",'value'=>"234")
                                            ),
                            'line-2'=>array('item-0'=>array('name'=>"item-210",'value'=>"567"),
                                           'item-1'=>array('name'=>"item-211",'value'=>"890")
                                            ))

);

 $rs = array ('1'=>array('name'=>'item-00', 'value'=>"abc"),
'2'=>array('name'=>'item-01', 'value'=>"def"),
'3'=>array('name'=>'item-10', 'value'=>"ghi"),
'4'=>array('name'=>'item-11', 'value'=>"jkl"),
'5'=>array('name'=>'item-100', 'value'=>"mno"),
'6'=>array('name'=>'item-101', 'value'=>"pqr"),
'7'=>array('name'=>'item-110', 'value'=>"stu"),
'8'=>array('name'=>'item-111', 'value'=>"vwx")
);
```

What I am trying to do is to replace the values in $pq for items with the values from $rs. 
for example item-01 in $pa to be replaced with abc from $rs.
What I tried is this:

```
foreach($rs as &$rs1) {
echo "first count :".$firstCount."<br>";
foreach($pq as $pages) {
    foreach($pages as $lines) {
        foreach($lines as &$item) {
            if ($item['name'] == $rs1['name']) { echo "matching </p>";
                    $item['value']=$rs1['value'];
                echo '<pre>';
                print_r($item);
                echo '</pre>';
                echo "<hr>";
                }


            }
       }

    }
}
```

When I print the values of $item from $pq, it prints the values from $rs, but when I print the whole array $pq, the values seem to be unchanged. 
Can anyone please help me find out what I am missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correctly looping through the items in each line by *reference*, but you're not doing it for the lines or pages themselves.  So you're updating the value of an item in a *copy* of the line, instead of the line itself.  It should be:

```
foreach($rs as $rs1) {
    echo "first count :".$firstCount."<br>";
    foreach($pq as &$pages) {
        foreach($pages as &$lines) {
            foreach($lines as &$item) {
                if ($item['name'] == $rs1['name']) { echo "matching </p>";
                        $item['value']=$rs1['value'];
                    echo '<pre>';
                    print_r($item);
                    echo '</pre>';
                    echo "<hr>";
                } 

            }
       }

    }
}
```

Note that the `&` in front of `&$lines` and `&$pages`.  Note also that `$rs1` *doesn't* need to be passed by reference, since you aren't changing anything in that array.

Answer (score 1):

You’ve assigned `$item` by reference but haven’t done the same for `$pages` and `$lines`. There will be no effect on the actual values of `$pq` unless you assign `$pages` by reference; similarly, the actual values of `$pages` will remain unchanged unless you assign `$lines` by reference. Therefore, in order to achieve what you want, change `foreach($pq as $pages)` to `foreach($pq as &$pages)` and `foreach($pages as $lines)` to `foreach($pages as &$lines)`.

Comment: You’re welcome. My answer preceded your accepted answer by 111 seconds but surely fell short of certain positive attributes which you found in that one.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a search array first so that you can match items easier:

```
$search = array_reduce($rs, function(&$prev, $current) {
    $prev[$current['name']] = $current;
    return $prev;
}, []);
```

This creates another array with the item name as the key. Then, you iterate over each item in `$pq` and modify the leaves where necessary:

```
foreach ($pq as &$page_data) {
  foreach ($page_data as &$line_data) {
    foreach ($line_data as &$item_data) {
      if (isset($search[$item_data['name']])) {
        $item_data = $search[$item_data['name']];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Make sure to use references at each level of iteration.